# Problemas con evento OnLoad

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

Estoy tratando que este `script` al momento que haga la petición en la base de datos me muestre los resultados sin tener que escribir, la única forma que sume es que escriba un valor numérico de otro modo no carga de forma automática

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" size="5" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"></td>
                <td><?php  echo  $nom_cli?></td>

                <td><?php echo"<a href='scarga.php?bl3=".$caso." ' target='_blank' > ".$caso."</a>"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['noap']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['uni_ca']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['pla_ca']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['num_int']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['tipo_pa']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['cod_it']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fechaa?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['dest']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['comenta']?></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="5"  name="acarreo[]"  value="<?php echo $acarreo;?>" title="ACARREO"></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="5"  name="pagocond[]"  value="<?php echo $pagocond=$row['pagocond']?>" title="PAGO DE CONDUCTOR"></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="5"  name="via[]"  value="<?php echo $via=$row['via']?>" title="VIATICO"></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="5"  name="peaje[]"  value="<?php echo $peaje=$row['peaje']?>" title="PEAJE"></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="5"  name="combust[]"  value="<?php echo $combust=$row['combust']?>" title="COMBUSTIBLE"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="txt3"  readonly/></td>
                <td><input name="update" type="image" src="save.png" height="" width="30"  /> </td>

<!-- language: lang-html -->

 function sum(e, inicio = false) {

        const tr = inicio ? inicio : e.path[2];

    tr.querySelector('.txt3').value = parseFloat(tr.querySelector('input[name="acarreo[]"]').value)
    - (parseFloat(tr.querySelector('input[name="pagocond[]"]').value)
    + parseFloat(tr.querySelector('input[name="via[]"]').value)
    + parseFloat(tr.querySelector('input[name="peaje[]"]').value)
    + parseFloat(tr.querySelector('input[name="combust[]"]').value)); 
}

window.onload = function () {
    document.querySelectorAll('input:not(.txt3)').forEach(el => {
      el.addEventListener('input', sum);
    }); // Añadimos el evento sum a todos los inputs salvo el de salida

    document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(el => {
        sum(null, el);
    });

}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicarte mejor? No se entiende cuál es el problema ni donde está el problema. Gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano desde el input acarreo hasta combust debe hacer un calculo de forma automatica apenas cargue la pagina